# why pop function in set pops the first element if we give intergers as input?

Tags: python, set

i created a set of integers and tried to pop the elements,every time pop function pops th first element but as per the documentaion of python pop function needs to pop the random value
if we give strings and input then the pop function pops the random value
could any one please clarify my doubt?

```
>>> a={1,2,3,4,5,6}
>>> a.pop()
1
>>> a.pop()
2
>>> a.pop()
3
>>> a.pop()
4
>>> a.pop()
5
>>> a.pop()
6
>>> a={"i","am","sai","kumar"}
>>> a.pop()
'am'
>>> a.pop()
'kumar'
>>> a.pop()
'sai'
>>> a.pop()
'i'
```

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.  Your example is not specific.  In the first part, with integers, you are popping an undefined list.  In the second example, you are popping from a `set`, which has no defined order -- thus, any expectation you have of popping in a particular sequence are unfounded.

Comment: "as per the documentaion of python pop function needs to pop the random value" - no it doesn't. `set.pop` only promises to pop *an* element. It promises absolutely nothing about how it decides which element to pop.

Comment: The order is implementation-dependent. In the implementation you use, it's probably in order by hash codes, and small integers get sequential hash codes. But strings have less predictable hash codes, so the order appears random.

Comment: [`set.pop()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.pop) clearly states: _Remove and return an **arbitrary** element from the set._ Arbitrary is not the same as random.

Comment: You said "pop function pops the first element". A set has no first element because it is an unordered collection. It might be, that the current implementation of Python delivers the values in ascending order if there are only small positive integers in that set, but you can't rely on that.

Answer (score -3):

when you pass values to a set it stored as sorted manner and uniquely. so your set variable is.

```
a={1,2,3,4,5,6}
```

and whenever you pop the values from set it remove first value from your set it does not mean whether you pass integer or pass strings.

```
a={'i', 'am', 'sai', 'kumar'}
```

so when you pass strings to set you must understand how it will stored.

```
a
{'kumar', 'sai', 'am', 'i'}
```

here you see your stored string in set. also whenever you pops from set it will pop your first value stored and so on..

```
a.pop()
'kumar'
a.pop()
'sai'
```

Comment: " it stored as sorted manner " no, it absolutely is not. The order is arbitrary, nor sorted

Comment: how will you explain that set stored arbitary values not in sorted manner